# Angularjs controller not working defined in a self invoking function hooked to a module

Tags: angularjs, module, controller

I have a page as follows. The controller is not working. Can someone please suggest me whats wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <title>AnjularJs Hello World</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="CustomerController">
    <h2>Customers</h2>
    <div id="Trial">{{name}}</div>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function () {
            alert("Inside Self invoking function. This is popping up.");
            CustomerController = function ($scope) { 
                alert("Inside controller. But this is NOT popping up");
                $scope.name = 'HeHe';
            };
            CustomerController.$inject = ['$scope'];
            angular.module('demoApp').controller('CustomerController', CustomerController);
        }());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alert inside the controller is not popping. The first alert is popping. Also the div with id="Trial" is not printing the name.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never create your `demoApp`-module. With `angular.module(name)` you **get** an already created module, with `angular.module(name, dependencies)` you **set**(create) a module. So simply add:

```
angular.module('demoApp', []);
```

above the line with `angular.module('demoApp')` and your cord works just fine:

```js
(function () {
    alert("Inside Self invoking function. This is popping up.");

    CustomerController = function ($scope) { 
                alert("Inside controller. But this is NOT popping up");
                $scope.name = 'HeHe';
            };
    CustomerController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  
    angular.module('demoApp', []);
            
    angular.module('demoApp').controller('CustomerController', CustomerController);
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="demoApp" data-ng-controller="CustomerController">
    <h2>Customers</h2>
    <div id="Trial">{{name}}</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank You, I got it. Its actually a trivial mistake. I shall accept the answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Kk. Glad I could help.